Quickfix python. How to omit StartTime and EndTime from config file without getting error
I do not want to include starttime and endtime in my config file, as I want to set NonStopSession=Y. As mentioned in the docs, setting NonStopSession=Y is incompatible with start and endtime flags. https://quickfixengine.org/n/documentation/
When i remove start and endtime, i get the following error. The reason i want to set NonStopSession=Y is that the acceptor seems to not reset my sequence numbers. As a result, at the start of each new day, my outgoing sequence number will be reset to 1, and will not be accepted by the acceptor
Error
I tried setting ResetOnLogon = N, as well as ValidateSequenceNumbers = N, all of which did not work.

You have made a few errors:

You are looking at the wrong docs.  You linked the docs for QuickFIX/n, which is the C# port.
Since you are using Python, you must be using the C++ build with the Python bindings.  So you need to look at the C++ docs: https://quickfixengine.org/c/documentation/

Now that we are looking at the correct docs, you will see that "NonStopSession" is not a supported feature in the C++ build.
(I cannot tell you when or if NonStopSession will ever be supported in C++.)


I suspect you do not actually need NonStopSession.  I think you actually just need to find out what your counterparty's session schedule is and set your config accordingly.
